# In hydrogen spectrum can hydrogen emit radiations too?

Tags: atomic-physics

In hydrogen spectrum if we pass a white light through hydrogen atom it will absorb some radiation, due to which it's electron will get excited. But electron will release energy in the form of radiation again so isn't it possible to get same wavelength of light which was initially absorbed? Also if it is true then many times we won't get correct as some special lines will again form on plate, right?

Comment: No. The radiation absorbed has to have energy exactly the difference between the respective energy levels. Emitted radiation will also have an energy exactly equal to the difference between energy levels. E.g, the wavelength of light absorbed causing an $n_1\rightarrow n_2$ excited state will be identical to that for an $n_2\rightarrow n_1$ emission.

Comment: "pass a white light through hydrogen atom" You cannot *pass light* through an atom. Light is classical electrodynamics , and passes through gas of Hydrogen , whereas an atom interacts quantum mechanically with a photon from the beam of light.

Comment: @annav I disagree with your comment on two points. One is merely semantic: "light" is a synonym for electromagnetic radiation, and electromagnetic radiation can be modeled using classical waves or with a quantized electromagnetic field. So light is not inherently classical. The second disagreement is more substantial: it is absolutely possible to model interactions between light and atoms using a classical EM field. You can find this worked out in Ch. 9 of the quantum optics text by Mandel and Wolf. Another relevant reference is Lamb and Scully, "The photoelectric effect without photons."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But electron will release energy in the form of radiation again so isn't it possible to get same wavelength of light which was initially absorbed?

It's possible that the atom will release a photon of the same frequency that originally impinged on it.

> Also if it is true then many times we won't get correct as some special lines will again form on plate, right?

Some is emitted, but at lower intensity than the source beam.  Due to the lower intensity, it will appear darker.

- The emission from the hydrogen is in all directions.  So the fraction emitted in the direction of the observer is small.  Therefore the intensity is lower.
- Some of the absorbed energy is re-emitted as higher frequency radiation.

Unless the hydrogen has another source of radiation, the emission from the hydrogen in the direction of the observer will always be less intense than the continuous spectrum falling on it.  That allows the absorption spectrum to be visible.

Answer (score 2):

An atom will only absorb radiation if the photon energy is close to the energy needed for the atom to transition to a higher energy state. So the absorbed radiation can only make the atom transition up to one of its quantized energy levels. When the atom transitions back down in energy, it will then emit light corresponding to one of the "special lines" in its spectrum.

If the photon energy is far away from the energy difference between two atomic energy levels, the atom will simply not absorb the radiation.

Answer (score 1):

The lowest excitation energy of atomic hydrogen is around 10.2eV. Green light is approx. 2.5eV, i.e. atomic hydrogen in its ground state can only be excited by UV radiation that has a four times higher energy (four times shorter wavelength) than green light. White light can scatter elastically off a hydrogen atom. This is called Rayleigh scattering, but I don't know if that has been observed. Hydrogen atoms have a very high binding energy to themselves and so they form H2 molecules under normal conditions. The Rayleigh scattering on molecular hydrogen gas under normal conditions seems similar to the Rayleigh scattering on air that makes the sky appear blue.

Comment: The Rayleigh scattering bit is necessarily wrong because of the size dependence https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fog_bow

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent Yes, but that's just a scaling factor. One would need a much thicker hydrogen atmosphere to get to the same effect, but everything else stays the same. My initial thought was that hydrogen has no polarizability and that the optical index of refraction would be orders of magnitude smaller, but that's not the case for molecular hydrogen. It is true for helium, though. But even then it's just a scaling factor. Everything else works the same.